# How to translate "the first {number}"?

Tags: nombres, articles, ordre-des-mots

For instance, in English we might say "I liked the first three, but..." etc.

I am interested in whether it is translatable both with a specific noun and without, e.g.:

> I liked the first three.
>
> I liked the first three books.

I tried googling it and saw both *les trois premières* et *les premières trois* in some examples...is there a difference with the placement, or a rule?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> J'ai aimé les trois premiers livres.
>   J'ai aimé les trois premiers.

It is not possible to put *premiers* before *trois* in these sentences. The number has to come very early in the order of adjectives. Although the number is classified as an adjective, it behaves a lot like a part of the article, and could be an article on its own (*j'ai lu trois livres cette semaine*).

I can't think of any context where you could say *<s>*les premiers trois livres*</s>. The only circumstance I can think of where *les premiers trois* is possible is if the number is part of a continuous unit of measure (all the examples in modern French on the [first few pages of Google Books search hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22les%20premiers%20trois%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_fr) fit this):

> Les premiers trois kilomètres furent faciles.
>   Les premiers trois mois d'abonnement sont à mi-tarif.

Even in these cases, it would be common to say *les trois premiers mois*, etc. The syntax *les premiers trois mois* implies that the three months are taken as a single unit. If the subscription is payable monthly, then *les trois premiers mois* is the only possible word order.

Comment: Ooh, good catch, important details with the measurements part.

Answer (score 2):

*Les trois premiers livres* or *les trois premiers* is the standard order.

*Les premiers trois* is odd and unusual, but it might be a shortcut for “le premier groupe de trois”. I guess it can be used orally to avoid ambiguity when the objects are grouped already.

Comment: Tu aurais un contexte où on peut dire « les premiers trois livres » ? (Avec livre = book, pas livre = pound.) Je sèche.